# How to control element that loaded with load query function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I updated posts in homepage with `query load function.` It enables me to show actual posts.
However, I have a problem. That is:
When I updated all posts without refresh whole page, I want to control element which loaded with load jquery function.
I loaded all actual post with this:

```
$( ".all-posts" ).load("/ .all-posts");
```

`.all-posts` element consists of `.post-edit class name.`

I want to find with this function:

```
$('.post-edit').click(function(){ 
alert("found element");
});
```

I fixed the problem with: 
I define function outside of load function and I used it normally and in load function's callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Replace:

```
$('.post-edit').click(function(){ 
  alert("found element");
});
```

with:

```
$('.all-posts').on('click', '.post-edit', function () { 
  alert("found element");
});
```